# how to create customized comment keyboard shortcut in android studio

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, android-studio, comments, to-do

By using `ctrl + /` we can comment / uncomment the current line in android studio

and we can create shortcuts commands from 
settings->Keymap

now my question is how to create new keyboard shortcut to comment the current line plus adding specific word "TODO" (or any other word) ???

for example:

```
String str="";
```

after pressing ctrl + / (or any other new shortcut) it should turn into this

```
// TODO: String str="";
```

I remember this is possible in Eclipse, what about Android Studio ? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio you can create custom macros and set them to whatever hotkey you want.

To create the macro:

- Go to *Edit → Macros → Start Macro Recording* and then enter your commands
- When done, in the same menu hit *Stop Macro Recording*
- Save it under some name.

To add a shortcut for the macro, go to *Settings -> Keymap -> Macros*,
find your macro and add a keyboard shortcut for it.